# Linux removable drive stuck problem when reading large number of files

Tags: linux, debian, usb-drive, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have several USB removable drives that I have connected to my single-board computer to use as a NAS. The operating system I am using is Armbian, which is a Debian-like system.

Ok, this is the problem:
A few days ago, I running a program called "Syncthing"(It's a tool for synchronizing files). I have a folder with large number of files. And I found that my movable disk being stuck when "Syncthing" is scanning files. It just hanging there without any tips. Every scan results in this.

So I write a Golang Program that reads a large number of files at the same time. Yes, stuck situation happened.

When stuck situation happening:

1. If you try to run "**df -h**", you will get stuck;
2. If you try to "**cd /mnt/mydisk**", you will get stuck, either;
3. Every program read file from this partition will be stuck without any
   message;

Seems like if you try to read anything about this movable drive, it freezes.
I have changed the "ulimit -n" but it still doesn't work.

If I reboot the system, everything is fine until I try to read large number files again.
I have the same problem with all three my usb movable disk and three single-board computer. They have the same system. So I assume this is a system problem.

**So what i wanna ask:**

**How can I locate the cause of this problem, and fix it?**

Here is some infomations about my System:

```
# uname -a

Linux orangepizero2 4.9.255-sun50iw9 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 1 23:28:34 UTC 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

```
# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sunxi-ohci/1p, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sunxi-ohci/1p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sunxi-ohci/1p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sunxi-ehci/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sunxi-ehci/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=sunxi-ehci/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M   (I changed usb driver to "usb-storage" before but doesn't work)
```

**When the disk hanging:**

```
# mount -l

sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=481084k,nr_inodes=120271,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=98840k,mode=755)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=600)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /var/log.hdd type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=600)
/dev/zram1 on /var/log type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard) [log2ram]
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/mydisk type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096) [MiniCache]  (<- this is my removable drive)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=98836k,nr_inodes=24709,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=98836k,nr_inodes=24709,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

```
# fdisk -l
...
(lot of device message)
...
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: EZAZ-00GGJB0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa2c21b65

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

```
# df -h
^C
(The command is hanging so I CTRL+C to suspend)
```

```
# strace df -h
execve("/usr/bin/df", ["df", "-h"], 0x7fde3826d8 /* 21 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55a32dc000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21083, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 21083, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb71e2000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0`C\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1458480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb71e0000
mmap(NULL, 1531032, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb7043000
mprotect(0x7fb71a0000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb71b0000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15d000) = 0x7fb71b0000
mmap(0x7fb71b6000, 11416, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb71b6000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fb71b0000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55821cf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb71ea000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fb71e2000, 21083)             = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55a32dc000
brk(0x55a32fd000)                       = 0x55a32fd000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6194224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 6194224, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb6a5a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2996, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2996
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "17 22 0:17 / /sys rw,nosuid,node"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "exec,relatime shared:11 - bpf bp"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "e shared:174 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,si"..., 1024) = 67
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 2115
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=27004, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 27004, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fb6a53000
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3900, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=820, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/security", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=40, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/lock", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=80, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/pstore", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/bpf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/hugepages", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/config", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=240, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/log.hdd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/log", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/mydisk",
```

(It's not that I haven't copy the whole message , but I'm stuck here.)

If I missing something important infomation, let me know and I will edit this post.

=======[ no new message from "**dmesg**" ]=======

```
root@armbian:~# dmesg
...
< lot of message >
...
[   18.358530] IPVS: Creating netns size=1928 id=3
[   18.517342] proc: unrecognized mount option "hidepid=invisible" or missing value
[   19.530203] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.530778] yzhang..read phyaddr=0, phyid=001cc916
[   19.542162] yzhang..read phyaddr=1, phyid=001cc916
[   19.559671] libphy: gmac0: probed
[   19.595908] sunxi-gmac gmac0 eth0: eth0: Type(7) PHY ID 001cc916 at 0 IRQ poll (gmac0-0:00)
[   19.610068] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.689280] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   20.014569] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   22.649063] sunxi-gmac gmac0 eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   22.649111] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   24.839356] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx 
 detected!
[   25.339475] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx detected!

root@armbian:~# start_read_files
This Go program will create 1000 threads(They are called goroutine in Golang) to read the total size of all files in /mnt/mydisk.
/mnt/mydisk has 139239 files.
I print the completed count every time there is an increase of 10000.
[Count]10000
[Count]20000
[Count]30000
[Count]40000
[Count]50000
[Count]60000
[Count]70000
(stuck here, Sometimes it is 10000, sometimes it is 80000 )

root@armbian:~# df -h
^C
(CTRL+C again...Now I can be stuck here...)

root@armbian:~# dmesg | tail
[   19.542162] yzhang..read phyaddr=1, phyid=001cc916
[   19.559671] libphy: gmac0: probed
[   19.595908] sunxi-gmac gmac0 eth0: eth0: Type(7) PHY ID 001cc916 at 0 IRQ poll (gmac0-0:00)
[   19.610068] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.689280] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   20.014569] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   22.649063] sunxi-gmac gmac0 eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   22.649111] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   24.839356] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx detected!
[   25.339475] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx detected!
(No any new message here.)
```

**■■■■■■■[ New Edit ]■■■■■■■**

Maybe **ntfs-3g** has some issues inside.
With several tests, I found how to restore my removable disk read and write without reboot whole system.

```
# kill -9 <pidof ntfs-3g>
# umount /dev/sdb1
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydisk
```

The problem seems to be getting more difficult. It's no longer a "Type a few commands and the problem is gone" trouble...

Comment: @shellter I have deleted this post in stackoverflow. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Have you had a look at `dmesg` output? What does it say when you're in the *stuck* situation?

Comment: @tink None of new message in `dmesg`. I edited my post and you can see what I got from my device...

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to leave the solution to the problem for people who have the same problem as me.

```shellsession
# ntfs-3g --version

ntfs-3g 2017.3.23AR.3 integrated FUSE 28
```

Update `ntfs-3g` if you can. In my case here, I reinstall a newest system image...

```shellsession
# ntfs-3g --version

ntfs-3g 2022.10.3 integrated FUSE 28
```

Solved! No more stuck...